# CSS - Blurry Text/Image - Transform:skew

Tags: html, css, transform, blurry

I get blurry text and image on my website because of:

```
transform:skew(0.25rad)
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="one">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.one{
    background:#323232;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    transform: skew(-0.25rad);
    padding:3px 20px;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin:0 -7px;
}
.one h3{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    transform:skew(0.25rad);
    color:#ffc70e;
    font-size:20px;
    letter-spacing:0.8px;
}
```

Comment: Which browsers have you tested/seen this with?

Comment: Ive tested with Firefox developer edition, and chrome (Latest version). I get more blurry content with Chrome.

Comment: I don't get any issue in both browser which you are saying, can you please elaborate.

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d1cpcdz4/) but the text looks identical with/without the skew. Can you confirm if you still see it and/or create a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The "blurry text" after 2d or 3d transforms with webkit browsers has been [discused many times][1]. But in your case, you can apply the transform only on a pseudo element so that your text isn't affected by the skew property.

It will also alow you to use only one tag in your markup :

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
body{color:#fff;font-weight: bold;font-size:50px;font-family:'Oswald',sans-serif;}

.parent {
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 5%;
    position:relative;
}

.parent::before {
    content :'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background: rgba(90,190,230,0.9);
    transform-origin:0 0;
    transform:skew(-10deg);
    z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    Hello
</div>
```

Comment: I still maintain the small font and font-weight set to bold masks the issue here.  Try it with font size 20px and font-weight normal, same as the website sample.. I suspect that's a bigger issue than just using pseudo elements for the container.

Comment: If I do this, is there a way to make the left side oblique also ?
And I think that it's going to be more difficult with the image on the "heroes" section if you check it out on overmvp.com

Comment: So ive notice that the blurry only happen when the page finish to load. When it's loading, it's not blurry. I tried removing any extra css or js but that dosen't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce the error using the original code.  Here's the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjhd1zax/1/)...

The text looks great in both Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

```
<div class="one">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
</div>
```

Don't forget we're dealing with Scalable Vector items (which deal with the shape of things.. the whole purpose of fonts in CSS is that they scale with good precision.)  This isn't like using HTML Canvas elements (which deals with pixels...)

If it looks different to you, I'm guessing something else is wrong.  Perhaps with the fonts loaded on your local machine?

Update:  I'm guessing the issue is related to your font choice, font-family: bignoodletitling;  When I check the components of your site, I see the font is actually `big_noodle_titling_oblique.woff`     hmmm.  You are taking an oblique font and straightening it out.  Can you start with a non-oblique font?  So yeah, I do see where you rotate then rotate back, exactly the same as you've stated in the original problem. So the oblique comment doesn't exactly apply.

Not quite sure how to help.  Perhaps try a few different fonts?  The JS fiddle is pretty clear.

One other idea to increase the crispness of the header text is to change the background color (.omvp-title-container) from #323232 to black (#000).

Comment: Agree I don't have the problem also in this jsfiddle. Check overmvp.com, the yellow titles in the gray bars are blurry, also the images in the heroes section are blurry.

Comment: Alright I understand what you mean. But I don't understand why some of the text is transformed without being blurred, and the other elements are. I took the transform example from this website, you can check out the menu on top, they are pretty much the same idea. http://us.battle.net/overwatch/en/

Comment: No I am not straightening it out :P, it comes like that by default. The skew is to make the gray box Oblique on the side, then I transform the text again so it stay straight

Comment: I understand. Some of the distortion is based on the small font size.  When I zoom in the words look VERY clear.  I also think it looks clearer with font-weight set back to bold instead of normal.

Comment: I agree also when I zoom it, it's super clear. But if I bold my text out, it's still burry, but it's even worst on my side, I don't know why.

Comment: It's true that #000 increase the crispness by a bit, but I can't have it black, and it also don't fix the problem truly

Comment: So ive notice that the blurry only happen when the page finish to load. When it's loading, it's not blurry. I tried removing any extra css or js but that dosen't fix the problem.